How to give run argument to a specific group in command line while run a java jar containing TestNG Projects
While running a jar e.g:
java -jar a.jar -testjar a.jar -xmlpathjar Test.xml
<!xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
 <test name="Test">
    <groups>
<run>
  <include name="brokenTests"/>
  <include name="checkinTests"/>
</run>
</groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

HOW TO GIVE ONLY brokenTests name in argument java -jar a.jar -testjar a.jar -xmlpathjar Test.xml
such that only this group testcases will be executed?
I'm expecting to give run groups in the argument itself.

If you would like to specify the group name via the commandline argument, then you should pass it as -groups (Here I am assuming that your executable jar is going to directly invoke the main method from within org.testng.TestNG java class
For more details, please refer to https://testng.org/#_command_line_parameters
If you are going to be making use of a suite file and you would still like to be able to specify the group name, then you should make use of a beanshell.
Please refer to the documentation for more details https://testng.org/#_beanshell_and_advanced_group_selection
Here's a sample xml file that shows how to make use of beanshell and then retrieve the groups name and use that to run is as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                    whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                    groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

You can refer to my blogpost for additional details https://rationaleemotions.com/beanshell_in_testng/
